# Android how to improve the download speed

Tags: java, android

My code download speed to reach the desired effect,how to improve the download speed

The code is as follows:

```
URL url = new URL("www.google.com");

HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

InputStream inStream = conn.getInputStream();

RandomAccessFile threadfile = new RandomAccessFile(saveFile, "rwd");

byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
int byteCount= 0;
while((byteCount = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
     threadfile.write(buffer,0,byteCount);
}
```

Comment: What makes you think this code is your bottleneck? Have you tried any sort of profiling? Would tweaking the buffer size yield any benefit?

Comment: pay your ISP to get more bandwidth:)

Comment: I think he wants to split and download as multipart files.

Comment: tweaking the buffer size has no obvious effect

Comment: Multithreading block download also has no obvious effect

Comment: The iphone and android download the same resource, iphone download speed than android download speed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your download speed will only be as fast as the bandwidth supplied to you by the ISP in use and the rate at which the server you request from sends back to you. Your code is fine, the speed depends primarily on the ISP.

Comment: If put aside the ISP, at the application layer have ways that improve download speed?

Comment: No... The only thing you can do is cache the data so they don't have to download it again. Sorry but that's all you can do..